# How to combat huge numbers produced by relu-oriented CNN

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, backpropagation

I have a CNN with a structure loosely close to AlexNet, see below:

```
Convolutional Neural Network structure:
100x100x3      Input image
25x25x12       Convolutional layer: 4x4x12, stride = 4, padding = 0
12x12x12       Max pooling layer: 3x3, stride = 2
12x12x24       Convolutional layer: 5x5x24, stride = 1, padding = 2
5x5x24         Max pooling layer: 4x4, stride = 2
300x1x1        Flatten layer: 600 -> 300
300x1x1        Fully connected layer: 300
3x1x1          Fully connected layer: 3
```

Obviously, with only max pooling and convolutional layers, the numbers will approach 0 and infinity, depending of how negative the weights are. I was wondering of any approaches to combat this, seeing as I would like to avoid large numbers.

One problem that arrises from this is if you use sigmoid in the final layers. Seeing as the derivative of sigmoid is `s(x)*(1-s(x))`. Having larger numbers will inevitably make the value of sigmoid 1, and so you'll notice on back prop, you have `1*(1-1)`, which obviously doesn't go down too well.

So I would like to know of any ways to try and keep the numbers low.

Tagged with python because that's what I implemented this in. I used my own code.

Comment: Any reason in particular you're using sigmoid? It's good for explainingthe concept but ReLU is far more common in practice. To avoid vanishing and exploding gradients, take a look at batch norm.

Comment: I'm not using sigmoid, I was just giving an example as to why huge numbers could be a problem. Ok, I did figure batch norm was the best way to do this, just wanted to make sure

Comment: Keep in mind that batch norm struggles as batch size gets smaller, which is common in imagery. If you have small batches you might want to check out group norm.

Comment: How small is small?

Comment: Group norm starts to have better performance when the batch size is below around 12. See figure 1 in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.08494

Comment: Thankyou! @jss367

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question on AI stack exchange (which it is better suited for) and through implementing the correct weight initialisation, numbers will neither explode or vanish on a forward *or* backward pass. See here: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/13106/how-are-exploding-numbers-in-a-forward-pass-of-a-cnn-combated